# How do we know if a compound can be oxidized?

Tags: organic-chemistry, oxidation-state

I'm studying organic chemistry, and I have to identify compounds that can be oxidized in some exercises I am doing.

For instance, an $\ce{R-CHO}$ can be oxidized further, but an $\ce{R_{3}-COH}$ cannot, and presently I can tell this only if I remember it by heart.

How do I know if a compound can be oxidized? Is there an algorithm/method to follow?

Comment: At this stage, I would recommend memorising. The mechanisms for redox reactions are often not trivial and sometimes unknown - it'll be difficult to come up with a systematic way to predict which compounds can be oxidised/reduced that isn't just a disguised form of "memorising".

Comment: I think your best bet other than memorizing right now is paying attention to the definition of "oxidation". What does oxidation mean? So, what do the compounds need to have in order to be oxidizable? Note that this is rather qualitative and can put you in trouble when you're not expecting it.

Comment: Oh and just by the way - since it's probably good to expand your chemical vocabulary - $\ce{RCHO}$ is called an *aldehyde* and $\ce{R3COH}$ a *tertiary alcohol*.

Comment: Every compound that contains carbon and is not $\ce{CO2}$ or a (hydrogen) carbonate can be oxidised.